# How to speed up this code implemented OpenCV

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, gpu, tbb

I need an advice for sample below code that requires lots of time for processing. I am developing project on OpenCV and have code blocks like this ( some of them are pictures ). What should I use for more speed? Like, OpenMP or TBB ( that's new in OpenCV and more complex, maybe some examples more helpful ) or GPU ( implementing entire project ) or Boost library or another I don't know 3rd party libraries.

i didn't write multithread on c++ before

thanks for helping now

sample code snippet:

```
for ( int j = 0; j < 90000000; j++ )
  for ( int i = 0; i < 90000000; i++ )
    for ( int k = 0; k < 90000000; k++ )
             // float point operations
```

Comment: I have simplified it for easy understanding. In the code blocks, can be other outside variables. Also, i need an advice, can you suggest which option can be easy to follow?

Comment: But, then we don't know where the real bottlenecks are. As shown, there isn't really much here to optimize.

Comment: first sorry for stealing your time, second the actual code blocks are very long and i didn't know how should i post here. Because of this, i must understand how can i handle double-for or triple-for? should i use tbb or openmp. which option is best solution for like situations?

Comment: for example; what are you using while impleting multithread programs? which is easy to understand, because i have a limited time. thks again

Comment: `((90 000 000^3) / 8) * bytes = 80 935 258.5 petabytes` - assuming you are indexing an optimally stored bit matrix. What are you trying to _actually_ do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you should ensure to have linear access to your memory. For example if you have a matrix:

```
cv::Mat mat(nrows, ncols, CV_32FC1);
```

linear access is:

```
for(int r = 0; r < mat.rows; r++)
{
  for(int c = 0; c < mat.cols; c++)
  {
    mat.at<float>(r,c) ... do something
  }
}
```

no linear access and much slower would be:

```
for(int c = 0; c < mat.cols; c++)
{
   for(int r = 0; r < mat.rows; r++)
   {
     mat.at<float>(r,c) ... do something
   }
}
```

as it declines caching. in addition techniques as OpenMP or TBB are preferable. But also parallizing via Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE) is could improve your code by factor 8 for each core, if your are able to compute with 8bit values.

Comment: Having linear access to memory isn't the big deal. Having linear access to ~80 Million Petabytes is going to prove more of a challenge...

Answer (score 1):

OpenMP is one of the easiest options. We can just have some preprocessors to parallelize for loops.
Here is a simple example of doing dot product using OpenMP

```
double Dot( int n, double x[], double y[] )
{
  int i;
  double dot_product = 0.0;

# pragma omp parallel \
  shared ( n, x, y ) \
  private ( i )

# pragma omp for reduction ( + : dot_product )

  for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
  {
    dot_product = dot_product + x[i] * y[i];
  }

  return dot_product;
}
```